# Jenkins unable to access Bitbucket Server (private repository) due to SSL certificate problem

Tags: ssl, jenkins, bitbucket

I have been looking for similar questions and although they are quite similar, I think the root cause of the issue is different, as none of the answers worked for me.

I am configuring Jenkins Snap on a Linux server to access a private repository in Bitbucket cloud.

I have tried multiple combinations, but the main setup is:

- Using https to connect to bitbucket
- Username / password jenkins credentials (Bitbucket app password)

I have tried using https://bitbucket... as well as https://USER@bitbucket... and https://USER:PW@bitbucket...

I have also tried setting the name (ID of the repository) in Advanced settings (Jenkins Git plugin).

If I try git commands from the command line it works perfectly.

I have also tried globally disabling sslVerify, but it didn't work. In any case, I think it's not the solution as it's trying to connect to Bitbucket cloud service, using an authorized and validated certificate.

When connecting the repository, it shows:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- https://USER@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/project/repo.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

If I run a build, it throws the following log:

```
13:51:32 Fetching upstream changes from https://USER@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git
13:51:32  > git --version # timeout=10
13:51:32  > git --version # 'git version 2.31.1'
13:51:32 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket credentials: so Jenkins can access Bitbucket repositories
13:51:32  > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://USER@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
13:51:32 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
13:51:32 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://USER@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
13:51:32 stdout: 
13:51:32 stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/project/repo.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
13:51:32 
13:51:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
13:51:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)
13:51:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
13:51:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:618)
13:51:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:847)
13:51:32    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1224)
13:51:32    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
13:51:32    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:537)
13:51:32    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
13:51:32    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:643)
13:51:32    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
13:51:32    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:515)
13:51:32    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1891)
13:51:32    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
13:51:32    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
13:51:32    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:440)
13:51:32 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
13:51:32 An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
13:51:32 [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
13:51:32 [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
13:51:32 [WS-CLEANUP] done
13:51:32 Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to add bitbucket certificate on the machin which run your job.